# List of products did not display

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I got:

store.js

```
import {productListReducer,productDetailsReducer,} from './reducers/productReducers'
const reducer = combineReducers({ productList: productListReducer, productDetails: productDetailsReducer,})

const initialState = {}
const middleware = [thunk]
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

productListReducer.js

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] }
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload.products,
        pages: action.payload.pages,
        page: action.payload.page,
      }
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

productActions.js

```
export const listProducts = (keyword = '', pageNumber = '') => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/products?keyword=${keyword}&pageNumber=${pageNumber}`
    )

    console.log(data) //data has items

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import { listProducts } from '../action/productActions'

const HomeScreen = ({match}) => {

  const keyword = match.params.keyword
  const pageNumber = match.params.pageNumber || 1
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList)
  const { loading, error, products, page, pages } = productList

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(keyword, pageNumber))

    console.log(productList) //empty
    console.log(products) //empty

  }, [dispatch, keyword, pageNumber])
```

I see that my data is fetching ok (`productActions.js)`, but then **I don't see any** `products into HomeScreen.js`

--Added
HomeScreen.js => return

```
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Row>
            {products > 0 && products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
```

--Update => index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---Redux
Into `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS` I see that payload has data,
somehow it's not passed...

sometimes also is showing this:
`GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)`

---Log from `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` & `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS`

-action-

[image]

-state-

[image]

===Dev tools / Network

When I see Network tab its as below:
[image]

also, into tab "Response" I see my data

--preview
[image]

--response
[image]

Comment: Logging `productList` and `products` immediately after calling `dispatch` will log the old values. Component can't see the updated state _until it re-renders_. Use the `useEffect` hook to log the updated values: `useEffect(() => { console.log(productList, products); }, [productList, productst])`

Comment: checked this:`{products: Array(0)}products: [][[Prototype]]: Object []`

Comment: How do you render `products` in `HomeScreen`?

Comment: update my question (put there my return)

Comment: Have you included Redux Provider in root of your app?

Comment: yes, added code from `index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With little help I resolved my issue. So issue was into `"productReducers.js"`, where I tried to pass `products: action.payload.products`, which was wrong. Should be just `products: action.payload`

Here is correct code:

```
case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
            {products > 0 && products.map((product) => (
```

Edit this to **products.length > 0** && ...

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` - I think it's array and we can't check length

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but try `products?.length &&`

Just be sure to handle what you want to display while it is undefined.

Comment: no error, still `array products it's empty`, only have this into log: `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'productList' and 'products'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: I have a hunch that the way you are setting your state in your reducer is causing the problem.

In your store.js, have initial state include `products: []`

Then, in your reducer
`case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST: return { ...state, loading: true }
`

You could remove the default state param of {products: []} in your reducer as well.

Comment: sorry did not help

Comment: Throw a debugger in here and see what your products are...

    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] }

Comment: and here....


case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload.products,
        pages: action.payload.pages,
        page: action.payload.page,
      }

Comment: I have added screen from log

Answer (score 0):

this

```
 products > 0 && products.map
```

to

```
 products?.map
```

Comment: `{loading: false, products: undefined}` and `GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)`......

Comment: `proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/products from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).`

Comment: @4est `please update your package.json`   with `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"`

Comment: got it as well :/

Comment: no, when I checked `Network` tab into Inspect/GoogleChrome, I see that name products contains: `Headers` = Get OK, Previes = there are items, I will add this to my question

Comment: Didn't get you @4est please can you send me response

Comment: I update question with log from Network tab